# The proper way to count Sh'mittah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As a follow up to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71660/questions-regarding-counting-for-shemitta-and-yovel) question, is it halachically preferable to count the seven year Sh'mittah cycle as:

"Not one year, not two years" (like we do when counting a minyan)

or

"Last year we counted four years" (like we do when counting the omer)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think I saw a halachic article that discussed counting, in general, and it asked this type of question regarding Shemittah (the 2nd question). It was meant as a serious article. Hmm, I wonder if I can locate this. It was a few years ago. I wonder if I should take issue with your linking my serious question into a Purim Torah question ;-)